# "Infinite scroll"-like. Make it fire before bottom

Tags: jquery

I'm using this small script to define if the user've scrolled to the bottom

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        if(!taskFired){
            taskFired = true;
            $("#loading_gif").css("display", "block");
            setTimeout(loadMoreMabs, 1500);
        }
    }

});
```

But I wan't it to fire the function loadMoreMabs *before* the bottom is reached. How would I do that? I've tried to + and - with the heights, but it's like I'm experimenting with something I don't really get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**What your question title suggests you want**

Subtract a value from `$(document).height()` something like 50 to start loading 50 pixels from the bottom.

```
if($(window).scrollTop() <= ($(document).height() - 50) - $(window).height()){
```

Here is a little demo in jsfiddle, I made a dummy function to fulfill the loadMoreMabs function

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/UwXaw/

Fires every time you are near the bottom and the 1500ms expire.

**Now to make it fire (immediatly) ONLY if it reaches the very bottom.**

*(since it actually suggests something else)*

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/UwXaw/1/

The trick is probably the `>=` in the equation, making sure it fires if the scrollTop is the same or HIGHER than the document minus the window height...

Comment: Very nice. Thanks! :-) I've tried this im sure, but forgot the extra () I think :)

Comment: @Kolind yeah those are important :p

Comment: @Kolind as a tip, you might want to keep track of the scrollTop position and add a rule to that statement that it only re-triggers the function if the new value in that event is HIGHER than the one you kept track of. This makes sure that the event is only triggered when people scroll DOWN.

Comment: It doesn't look like the new jsfiddle works for me. Right now it's firing even if I scroll up as you mentioned.

Comment: @Kolind like this http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/UwXaw/6/ though do keep in mind that it assumes that the function `loadMoreMabs` adds more height and thus you can scrollTop further down AFTER it has been completed (and so trigger it again)

Comment: The new jsfiddle doesn't seem to work either. It's not even triggering an alert(); when I scroll to bottom.

Comment: @Kolind forgive me, trying to do this while watching out for Planetside 2 beta keys made me sloppy; this one works better/is a better example (and assumes the function `loadMoreMabs` blocks firing off another function until it is done) http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/UwXaw/10/

Comment: No problem. But it still doesn't work. lol.. I don't know what's happening :s

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12174/discussion-between-sg3s-and-kolind)